# How to use TList for storing binary MD5 and SHA-1 hash digests?

Tags: hash, md5, lazarus, freepascal, digest

I have a program that computes various hashes of files from Folder and FolderB and then compares the results to make sure both are the same. The filenames are stored in a StringListUTF8 and the hashes are stored in StringLists, as strings.

The trouble is, although it works fine for small data volumes, if there's hundreds of thousands of files, the program falls over and\or takes a really long time, especially when SHA-1, SHA256 and SHA512 are incorporated.

I want to make it faster and more efficient by storing the binary (integer representation) of the hash digest in a TLIst and then comparing the values as integers or something. I figure I can use a TList and add the values to that and if I create two TLists for each of the two folders and the hash digests are put into each of them, I can then easily and rapidly compare the individual hashes if there's any differences, and if they are the same, I can compare that in a flash as well.

By way of simple demonstration, I've created a really basic stripped down version of the current program, and then you'll hopefully see where I am trying to do the binary storage. This simple demo just hashes each file in FolderA and stores the string versions in a StringList. The same is repeated for FolderB. Those two StringLists are then hashed to see if they match, or not. The real program also checks each entry in the list if there's a mis-match to work out which files are wrong.

Below is the code of the simplified version :

```
// Choose Source Folder
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if SelectDirectoryDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    label1.Caption := SelectDirectoryDialog1.FileName;;
  end;
end;

// Choose Second Folder
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if SelectDirectoryDialog2.Execute then
  begin
    label2.Caption := SelectDirectoryDialog2.FileName;
  end;
end;

// Compare FolderA against FolderB
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  FolderA, FolderB : TStringListUTF8;
  ListOfHashesA, ListOfHashesB : TStringList;
  HashOfFolderA, HashOfFolderB : string;
  ListOfBinHashesA : TList;

begin
  try
    FolderA := TStringListUTF8.Create;
    FolderA := FindAllFilesEx(SelectDirectoryDialog1.FileName, '*', True, True);
    ListOfHashesA := HashFolder(FolderA); // List of hashes of all files in FolderA
    // This is where I hope to replace the use of strings for binary representation
    // of the hashes
    //ListOfBinHashesA := BinaryHashFolder(FolderA); // List of hashes of all files in FolderA

    // Now generate hash of the FolderA hash list itself. Faster than comparing each hash value line by line
    HashOfFolderA := Uppercase(MDPrint(MDString(ListOfHashesA.Text, MD_VERSION_5)));
  finally
    FolderA.Free;
  end;

  try
    FolderB := TStringListUTF8.Create;
    FolderB := FindAllFilesEx(SelectDirectoryDialog2.FileName, '*', True, True);
    ListOfHashesB := HashFolder(FolderB); // List of hashes of all files in FolderB
    // Now generate hash of the FolderB hash list itself. Faster than comparing each hash value line by line
    HashOfFolderB := Uppercase(MDPrint(MDString(ListOfHashesB.Text, MD_VERSION_5)));
  finally
    FolderB.Free;
  end;

  if HashOfFolderA = HashOfFolderB then
  begin
    ShowMessage(HashOfFolderA + ' ' + HashOfFolderB + ' : MATCH');
  end
  else
    ShowMessage(HashOfFolderA + ' ' + HashOfFolderB + ' : MIS-MATCH');
end;

{ I want this function to add a method of computing and then storing the binary hash, as an integer,
  and then return a big TList full of the values for FolderA, and then I'll call it again for FolderB :
}
function TForm1.BinaryHashFolder(FolderName : TStringListUTF8) : TList;
var
  BinList : TList;
  i : integer;
begin
  try
  BinList := TList.Create;
  for i:= 0 to FolderName.Count -1 do
    begin
      // Compute binary hash val for each file and add to the TList
      // BinList.Add(MD5File(FolderName.Strings[i], 2097152)));
    end;
  finally
    result := BinList;
  end;
end;

// Looks through the list of filenames and computes string version of MD5 value for each file
// Each hash value is added to a string list and that whole list is then returned
function TForm1.HashFolder(FolderName : TStringListUTF8) : TStringList;
var
  slHashList : TStringList;
  i : integer;
begin
  try
    slHashList := TStringList.Create;
    slHashList.Sorted := true;
    for i:= 0 to FolderName.Count -1 do
    begin
      slHashList.Add(Uppercase(MD5Print(MD5File(FolderName.Strings[i]))));
    end;
  finally
    result := slHashList;
  end;
end;
```

Hopefully one of you could help me finish off the use of TList because I can't get it to work. I don't even know if I'm on the right lines? Any advice for a better solution, welcomed.

Note I am using Freepascal 2.6.4 and Lazarus 1.4.4

Comment: TList holds pointers. Your hashes will be larger than pointers. You'd be better off creating a dynamic array of value types. However, you list that stores the hash is not the cause of your problem. Storing them as strings is just fine and isn't going to hurt you. Your problem is elsewhere. Instead of jumping to the wrong conclusion you should debug your program to properly identify the issue.

Comment: I always respect your experience David but are you quite sure? I was always of the view that converting stuff to strings was more the final step you'd take with data. At the moment, lets suppose FolderA contains 800K files, and FolderB contains 800K files. That's means that when comparing, there's two stringlists of hash values with 800K entries held in each. I'm sure that computing, storing and then comparing two binary integer lists of 800K integers is going to be exponentially quicker and is much more efficient than computing, storing, converting and then comparing 800K string hashes.

Comment: You are sorting and comparing?!! Every time you add a hash.  That's your problem then.  Whether you do that with a string or binary it won't make any real difference. Binary will likely be faster but the algorithmic complexity is the fundamental problem. That's what you need to fix.

Comment: Not every time...let me explain. As in the example above, all files in FolderA are searched for, and then hashed. The hashes are stored in a StringList. Then all files in FolderB are searched for, and then hashed, and stored in a second stringlist. Then the hashes from FolderA and FolderB are compared one by one but only if the stringlists are different. If they are the same, this individual comparison is not needed.

Comment: Yes but you are sorting the list. Every time you add to the list there is an insertion. Better to populate the list, and then sort.

Comment: Mmmm, yes. You are right. I've tweaked it so that a) the lists are each only sorted once, just before comparison, b) I've set the stringgrids to disabled and invisible until the end when they are needed and c) I only populate the stringgrids with data that does match. If both folders match, then the user just gets a note to say "all is OK". In a test of 8gb of data using my new version against the previous, it was 2m 20s vs 1m 19s! So that's nearly 50% faster. So I guess you were right....again!